# Does anything similar to dbms_lob.INSTR exist in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I'm looking for a query similar to this one from Oracle.

```
SELECT * FROM documents
WHERE dbms_lob.INSTR(document, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('home'),1,1) > 0;
```

Because I want to find the word home in all documents of my data base, and the documents are storing in .blob.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What are the data types of the columns in SQL Server?

Comment: What version of SQL server are you on because that makes a big difference. Also do you mean all tables where you said all documents?

Comment: Version; SQLServer2012 and the columns are BLOB. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

I do it with a convert and the [patindex() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx). My binary column is of data type "image".

```
patindex('%home%', convert(varchar(max), convert(varbinary(max), document)))
```

This is basically the same as this one in Oracle.

```
dbms_lob.instr(document, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('home'), 1, 1)
```

In SQL Server there are different convertions possible: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx.